# If statement for user input on time

Tags: jquery, if-statement, time, user-input

I am trying to create a if statement where the user must select a time between 7am and 16pm. I have searched on Stack, WESchools, MDN and written the if statement in a multiple of ways and still can not get it to work correctly.

Either the alert pops up, no matter the time inputted and the code wont run, or the code will run no matter the time put in by the user.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="content-container">
  <div id="table-section" class="table-section">
  <div>
    <button class="confirm">Confirm</button>
    <button class="reset" type="reset">Reset</button>
 <table id="table_id" class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th id="th-reg">Registration</th>
    <th id="th-name">Name</th>
    <th id="th-cmr">Current Miles Range</th>
    <th id="th-cni">Miles needed for next trip</th>
    <th id="th-tl">Hours to charge for next trip</th>
    <th id="tpoc">Time Leaving</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><span class="answer"></span><input class="reg question" id="car-1-reg" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Registration"></input></td>
    <td id="car-1-name" class="name value-reset"></td>
    <td><span id="car-1-cmra" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-1-cmr" class="cmr question" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles Left"></input></td>
    <td><span id="car-1-mtnc" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-1-mtnc" class="mtnc question" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles needed"></input></td>
    <td id="car-1-charge-needed" class="charge"></td>
    <td id="car-1-tl" class="tl"><span class="answer time-input" type="text"></span><input class="time" type="time" min="07:00:00" max="16:00:00" required></input></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
   <button id="generate-time-table" class="generate">Generate Schedule</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".confirm").click(function() {
  var _times = document.getElementsByClassName("time");
  if ((_times > 7) && (_times < 16)) {  
    $("#table_id tbody tr").each(function() {
      if ($(this).find(".reg").val() == "") {
      $(this).find(".name").text("Please enter valid Registration");
  }
  var cmra = $(this).find(".cmr").val();
  var mtnc = $(this).find(".mtnc").val();
  if ((cmra != null && cmra != "") && (mtnc != null && mtnc != "")) {
    var miles = Math.ceil((parseInt(mtnc - cmra)) / 44);
    $(this).find(".charge").text(miles);
  } else if (cmra == null || cmra == "") {
    $(this).find(".charge").text("Please enter the current miles left");
  } else if (mtnc == null || mtnc == "") {
    $(this).find(".charge").text("Please enter the mtnc  left");
  }
})
} else {
  alert("Please enter a time between 7:00am and 16:00pm");
}
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Coxy/bv5jct7n/20/

Any pointers would be really appreciated, I just can't figure out what's wrong no matter which way I write it.

Comment: Please reduce the linked demo to the minimum ("*[mcve]*") code necessary to reproduce the problem you're experiencing. Unless the cars or solar chargers are relevant to your problem we don't need to see it. Reduce the cruft, expose the problem. Once that's done please include the entirety of that reduced - again: ***minimal*** *complete verifiable example* code - in your question, don't just link to it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, I think I have done what you asked, if there is something still wrong with it let me know and I will try again. I out the snippet on Stack that I am having trouble with, then the full code on Fiddle in case someone wants or needs a bigger clearer picture. Thank you for correcting me on how it should be, I will take not going forward.

Comment: Hi you need to validate that thing inside your `$("input[type='time']").change(function() {..` when user select any time validate it before putting value in `span` tag .

Comment: Thank you Swati, amazing reply! I will have  a go at that now! Thank you :D

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is that you are trying to get the values using here `var _times = document.getElementsByClassName("time");` directly, `getElementsByClassName` returns an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), and an time input, without any extra configuration, will return the time in format 'HH:MM' as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

Comment: Thank you h3nr1ke, That helps, I have moved the code to Swati's suggestion and still not running properly, I will have a look at the links and try again thank you .

Comment: Simply use `$(this).val().split(":")[0]` to get hrs and then simply use if statement to check if the value which is entered by user is `greater than 7` and `less than 16` .Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/zg5ot6n1/4/)

Comment: So this is what I was trying: // $("input[type='time']").change(function() {
  
//   if (($("input[type='time']")> 7) && ($("input[type='time']") < 16)) {
// $(this).closest('td').find("span").show().text($(this).val());

// $(this).hide();
//   } else {
//     alert("Please enter a time between 7:00am and 16:00pm");
//   }
// });

But I had a duplicate at the bottom of the page, making the alert pop up every time.lol I have amended my code to match thank you again Swati, I can't up vote a comment to solve the question I'm afraid but if you do post an answer i'd like to up vote it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get `hh` part from time input and then compare it with `hours` i.e : if the `hh` is `>= 7` and `<= 16` depending on this show error message .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("input[type='time']").change(function() {
  var time = $(this).val().split(":")[0]; //get hrs
  console.log($(this).val().split(":")[0]);
  //check hrs if grater then or lss then or not
  if ((time >= 7) && (time <= 16)) {
    //show value in span
    $(this).closest('td').find("span").show().text($(this).val());
    $(this).hide(); //hide that input

  } else {
    //show error 
    $(this).closest('td').find("span").show().text("please enter time below 16:00 and greater the 07:00")

  }

});

$(".reset").click(function() {
  $(".answer").html("");
  $("input").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-container">

  <div id="table-section" class="table-section">

    <div>
      <button class="confirm">Confirm</button>
      <button class="reset" type="reset">Reset</button>
      <table id="table_id" class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id="th-reg">Registration</th>
            <th id="th-name">Name</th>
            <th id="th-cmr">Current Miles Range</th>
            <th id="th-cni">Miles needed for next trip</th>
            <th id="th-tl">Hours to charge for next trip</th>
            <th id="tpoc">Time Leaving</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="answer"></span><input class="reg question" id="car-1-reg" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Registration"></input>
            </td>
            <td id="car-1-name" class="name value-reset"></td>
            <td><span id="car-1-cmra" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-1-cmr" class="cmr question" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles Left">
            </td>
            <td><span id="car-1-mtnc" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-1-mtnc" class="mtnc question" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles needed">
            </td>
            <td id="car-1-charge-needed" class="charge"></td>
            <td id="car-1-tl" class="tl"><span class="answer time-input" type="text"></span><input class="time" type="time" min="07:00:00" max="16:00:00" required>
            </td>

          </tr>

        </tbody>

      </table>
```